# How to make a gradle build finish successful with checkstyle errors?

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

I haven an Android Gradle build that is run on Jenkins.

Jenkins checks checkstyle warnings and errors and publishes the results. If there is a checkstyle error the build stops and is marked as failed. Jenkins also stops and does not publish the checkstyle report.

How can I let the build run through even with checkstyle errors?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an even nicer and easier solution than that from Rene.
Just add:

```groovy
checkstyle {
   ignoreFailures = true
}
```

to your build.gradle file.

Comment: nicer and easier is a matter of taste I guess. But to clarify: the difference to my solution is, that you need to have the checkstyle plugin applied (usually you have) and this solution applies to _all_ tasks of type Checkstyle. If you need a more fine grained solution setting this on tasklevel is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

The Checkstyle task can be configured to ignore failures:

```groovy
checkstyleTask.ignoreFailures = true
```

Comment: And where would you put that line?

Comment: you can put that into your build.gradle file after you applied the checkstyle plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution which provides the above functionality along with error reporting in html format and puts all checkstyle configuration in gradle, take a look at [gradle-estilo-plugin](https://github.com/anshulverma/gradle-estilo-plugin).

On a side not, I must point out that I wrote this plugin myself and I use it extensively in all of my projects.